# Difference between accuracy with location

Tags: objective-c, core-location

When setting the location , we would like to get the best battery performance, and the least accuracy( but not using the "significant change" )

When setting the manager i do :

```
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy =kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
```

Whats the different between  :

```
 kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers

 kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
```

and the rest of them .

as far as i see, even when the device is on the table, both gives me background locations in same frequency, that is every few seconds .

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kCLLocationAccuracyBest)

**kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers**

Accurate to the nearest three kilometers.

**kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer**

Accurate to the nearest kilometer

Note : It never says about the updating frequency it is the accuracy parameter depending on the range

Comment: common... i could read my self that one is kilometer and one is 3.. question is for developers than experienced that and can tell what happens in real life ..